# How can I run a coroutine but not wait for it?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a non-async function that looks like this:

```
def do_stuff(on_finished):
    result = # complicated calculations here
    on_finished(result)
```

The callback I pass in looks more or less like this:

```
async def on_finished(self, result):
    response = await post_over_http(result)
    self.last_status = response.status
```

When I call `do_stuff`, what I want to happen is this:

1. `do_stuff` executes and calls `on_finished`
2. `on_finished` executes, posts the result over HTTP, and then returns immediately.
3. `do_stuff` now returns immediately.
4. Later, the HTTP response comes back, and execution returns to the second line of `on_finished`.

Critically, I **don't want do_stuff to be async**. For architectural reasons, I want `do_stuff` isolated from the asynchronous nature of the network code, so I don't want to have to make it async just because some code using it is async.

In JavaScript this would be no problem - with basically the above code directly transcribed to JavaScript, I'll get the desired behavior. `onFinished` would return a Promise which `doStuff` doesn't wait for and returns immediately, but when the Promise resolves later the second line of `onFinished` runs. Is this possible in Python? I'm unsure of how to achieve it. With the above code I think I just create a coroutine in the last line of `do_stuff` but never call it.

Comment: coroutines require an event loop. If you need it as *"isolated from the asynchronous nature"* - try another parallel approaches

Comment: https://stackabuse.com/overview-of-async-io-in-python-3-7/

Comment: Given your arch. constraints, it might not be easy to integrate the creation and kickoff of the event loop in the main

Answer (score 8):

You can design your `do_stuff` function like this:

```
def do_stuff(on_finished):
    async def _do_complicated_calculation():
        result = # do the calculation here & the post request
        await on_finished(result)
    asyncio.ensure_future(_do_complicated_calculation())
    return "ok"
```

When you call `do_stuff(...)` the complicated calculation will be added to the asyncio event loop, so it gets executed asynchronous. You should have the event loop running in a different thread if you don't plan to start it in the main thread.

Since `_do_complicated_calculation()` is async, do_stuff will return `"ok"` first and after your calculations have finished, `on_finished(...)` is being called.

Comment: I like it. But now show how the creation of the event loop ties in

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the JavaScript analogy, what you want is something like:

```
def do_stuff(on_finished):
    result = ...
    asyncio.create_task(on_finished(result))
```

The last line spawns a task that processes the result without actually waiting for it to finish. This is what you'd get in JavaScript by simply creating a promise, whereas in Python you have to be a bit more explicit.

Of course, `do_stuff` must run inside an event loop, and the calculations must not block (or take too long to complete), but the same would be the case in JavaScript.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something. This isn't working for me - here's a [minimal example](https://repl.it/repls/EminentIdenticalDrupal).

Comment: @JackM That's just because `main()` (and with it the whole program) exits before `on_finished` has had a chance to be called. Add e.g. `await asyncio.sleep(1)` at the end of `main()` and it will work.

Comment: Okay, that works, but in the [updated example](https://repl.it/repls/EminentIdenticalDrupal) you can see there's another problem - `do_stuff` returns before `on_finished` is executed. In the JS equivalent of this code, `on_finished` would execute straight away, up until the first `await`, and only then suspend, and go back up to`do_stuff`.

Comment: @JackM You can do that, but it's not pretty - you can make `on_finished` an ordinary `def` which does the non-async stuff first and returns a coroutine that actually awaits - [like this](https://pastebin.com/ZaRXMtz9).

Answer (score 0):

This is why Javascript behaves differently from Python.

> ECMAScript 2015 introduced the concept of the Job Queue, which is used
>   by Promises (also introduced in ES6/ES2015). It's a way to execute the
>   result of an async function as soon as possible, rather than being put
>   at the end of the call stack.
>
> Promises that resolve before the current function ends will be
>   executed right after the current function.

https://nodejs.dev/the-nodejs-event-loop

Answer (score 0):

Rather than pass a callback have the synchronous function return the its result and use `run_in_executor` to make the call from the asynchronous code to the synchronous code that will be running on its own thread.

```
def do_stuff():
    result = # complicated calculations here
    return result

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    result = await loop.run_in_executor(None, do_stuff)
    response = await post_over_http(result)
    self.last_status = response.status
```

Untested.

Answer (score 0):

Found this thread in 2023, I didn't see any answers that actually worked. Had to dig around the comments till I found one by [@user4815162342](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1600898/user4815162342) at this [pastbin](https://pastebin.com/ZaRXMtz9), so here it is (slightly edited) for anyone that comes after me:

(OP, your 2. and 4. requirements are contradictory. You want `on_finished` to return immediately, but also come back to it after receiving the response from `post_to_http`. I believe that might not have been what you really meant, so here's the answer with `on_finished` not returning immediately.)

```
import asyncio

def do_stuff():
    result = 'result of compicated calculations' # complicated calculations
    asyncio.create_task(on_finished(result))

async def on_finished(result):
    response = await post_over_http(result)
    # self.last_status = response.status 
    print(response)

async def post_over_http(result):
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    return 'Do something with response from post request'
 
async def main():
    print('start')
    do_stuff()
    print("end")
    await asyncio.sleep(4)
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```